# How do I prevent the text from my hero area from overflowing for mobile users?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm customising a wordpress theme ([Impact](https://templatemag.com/demo/Impact/)) but the header / hero area size is not working for my site (text box gets pushed down and is hidden in the overflow area below).

This is one of the problematic pages: https://better.sg/content/interview-jonathan-tan-jerry-lim-contribute-sg/

I have a hero image with a text box on top that uses CSS and JS. The size of the hero image (which I set using VH) and the position of the text box (which adjusts on load due to a javascript) cause the text box to be positioned too low for some mobile users. I am not sure how to fix this. What is causing the text box to be pushed below the hero area and how do I either (a) adjust the hero image size to account for longer titles or (b) make sure the text title does not adjust down below the bottom of the hero image?

The style sheet is here: https://better.sg/wp-content/themes/Impact/css/style.css
And my init.js is here: https://better.sg/wp-content/themes/Impact/js/init.js (not sure if this is the one causing the problem).

I'm having trouble debugging, so any advice is appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Go to your WordPress website open click on Themes and then select Customize. In Customize select additional CSS and add the following code and save it.

```
@media(max-width:768px){
     #single-page-slider{
          height:auto;
       }
       #single-page-slider .item-active .container .gap{
           width:80%;
        }
}
```

Comment: seems to do the trick. Not sure why I didn't just think of overriding the height tag with a media query.... :/
the gap was a useful change as well. Thanks!

Comment: It happens XD  event at later stages .

Answer (score 0):

You could use `@media` rules in CSS ([link](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp)) to reduce the size of your header images on smaller screen sizes